# Autodesk Forge: Download checklist attachment

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge

When I retrieve a checklist instance, I got the following section related to attachment.

```
    {
  "type": "instance_item_attachments",
  "id": "5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee",
  "attributes": {
    "name": "6856ad10-6ab0-11e9-9150-9fda3da0626e.png",
    "attachmentType": "OSS",
    "mimeType": "image/png",
    "uploadStatus": "COMPLETED",
    "urns": [
      {
        "urn": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.gy4mB910SneymU86Gc4O0A?version=1",
        "type": "WIP"
      },
      {
        "urn": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/ede3de59-1b68-485c-82fe-f1f2af3442fe.png",
        "type": "OSS"
      },
      {
        "urn": "urn:adsk.checklists.cs.attachment:58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b/5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee",
        "type": "CHECKLIST"
      }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2019-04-29T18:55:51.334Z",
    "updatedAt": "2019-04-29T18:55:54.137Z",
    "createdBy": "TAKCJQU6HGXW",
    "modifiedBy": "TAKCJQU6HGXW",
    "permittedActions": [
      "canArchive",
      "canEdit"
    ],
    "permittedAttributes": [
      "mimeType",
      "uploadStatus"
    ]
  },
  "links": {
    "self": "/containers/58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b/instance_item_attachments/5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee"
  },
  "relationships": {
    "container": {
      "meta": {
        "relation": "primary",
        "readOnly": false
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/containers/58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b/instance_item_attachments/5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee/relationships/container",
        "related": "/containers/58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b/instance_item_attachments/5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee/container"
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "containers",
        "id": "58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b"
      }
    },
    "item": {
      "meta": {
        "relation": "primary",
        "readOnly": false
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/containers/58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b/instance_item_attachments/5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee/relationships/item",
        "related": "/containers/58b8afcf-d7cd-49ad-aa10-78c50610761b/instance_item_attachments/5a0a2acf-b02a-4b88-86cc-962c3831bdee/item"
      },
      "data": null
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I want to download this attachment, the provided URN is: wip.dm.prod/ede3de59-1b68-485c-82fe-f1f2af3442fe.png

If I try to access it using the following link, it says not found

> *developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/b30e3ffe-333b-446c-b834-e2f2141096b4.png*

However, if I changed the URL a bit (by adding objects), it works fine.

> *developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/**objects**/b30e3ffe-333b-446c-b834-e2f2141096b4.png*

Am I doing something wrong here? or this is a bug in the provided urn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to [Adam Nagy reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55949717/4838205), you would need to break the URN. From your original question:

```
urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/ede3de59-1b68-485c-82fe-f1f2af3442fe.png
```

In .NET you can try (using System.Linq):

```
string bucketKey = urn.Split("/").First().Split(":").Last();
string objectName = urn.Split("/").Last();
```

Then rebuild as:

```
string attachemtnUrl = string.Format("{0}/oss/v2/buckets/{1}/objects/{2}", BASE_URL, bucketKey, objectName);
```

And you'll also need the `Authorization` header with a valid access token.

Answer (score 1):

The **id / urn** of an object in **OSS** (Object Storage Service) contains the **bucket name** and **object name** after the "**urn:adsk.objects:os.object:**" section.

There is a tutorial on downloading a file https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/download-file/

It shows that the reply concerning an **item** contains both the **id** and the actual **URL** of the download link under the **storage** section:

```
"storage": {
  "data": {
    "type": "objects",
    "id": "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/977d69b1-43e7-40fa-8ece-6ec4602892f3.rvt"
  },
  "meta": {
    "link": {
      "href": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/wip.dm.prod/objects/977d69b1-43e7-40fa-8ece-6ec4602892f3.rvt"
    }
  }
}
```

There you can see the connection between the **id** and the **URL** you can use to download the file

Comment: Checklist provides the following URN: urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/ede3de59-1b68-485c-82fe-f1f2af3442fe.png

If I tried GetItem using the following URL, it says not found
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/b.a2285238-251f-473d-9e4f-1843865387db/items/urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/b30e3ffe-333b-446c-b834-e2f2141096b4.png

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in my case I have to extract bucket key and object name from urn and use the following API call https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-GET/

I can do this, but i would expect checklist to provide an item id

Comment: You only have an "item" for files that are part of the BIM 360 Docs (or A360, Fusion Team, etc) file system like shown here https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/ids-data-management-api - i.e. if you can find the file by iterating through your hubs/projects/folders

Comment: The checklist attachments are not listed as items. I hope this is not a big ask, can we a sample code for downloading the checklist attachment? Thanks.